# Why is error_reporting being ignored in php.ini?

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, error-logging

I have set `error_reporting = none` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`and ran `sudo service apache2 restart` yet when I tail `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I still get stuff like `PHP Notice:xxxxxxxxxxxxx`showing up.

Why is this?

Comment: What does `var_dump(error_reporting());` show?

Comment: Should error reporting be off rather than none? Also have you checked these three: `error_reporting = E_ALL`,`display_errors = off`,`log_errors = off`

Comment: The value for error_reporting in my phpinfo is 22527 - if that is what you mean?

Comment: @TheHumbleRat sorry yes, it is = off. So is display_errors. log_errors was On but I have changed it to Off, reloaded apache and it's still logging....

Comment: @James how strange, maybe remove this line also `error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log` or the equivalent in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `0` rather than `none` to the `error_reporting` parameter in your php.ini:

```
error_reporting=0
```

The `error_reporting` parameter value is an integer bitmask where each bit represents different error level. `0` means all error levels are off, including notice.

You can also override default error_reporting value in your individual PHP script by using the following statement:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

This will turn all error reporting off for the current script's execution only.

Comment: it's not working. I've changed error_reporting to 0 yet phpinfo still says 22527 for 'local value' (master value is 0)

Comment: Master value is the one that is set by php.ini directive. In your case this value is 0 which is correct because you set error_reporting=0 in your php.ini. The local value is overridden value in the current script. It is likely that phpinfo overrides error_reporting itself.

Comment: In any case, I think your code should work correctly, because unless you override error_reporting parameter, it will use the master value.